# Binding dependency property on every control to a single propertty. can it be done?

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls, binding

i have threee controls and this is wat i need to accomplish

ctrl1  - dep property isvisible - bound to - visible property in VM
ctrl2 - same dep property -same binding
ctrl3 - same dep property - same binding

at run time i need to pass the name of this control to the property and then decide whether it needs to be visible or not in the VM property. how do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Each and every control must have a name property.Suppose you have not change the name property the they automatically set the name property as that controls name.(e.g. text box1 control is there then their default name property is name text1, text box2 have text2 and your given name property is txtrno.) At the time of setting the name property we must to give name with short form of that controls. g.e. for command = cmd, labe=lbl.
In project for for understanding of about the controls the name property is must.